# Как удалить произвольный элемента стека Forth

Tags: стек, forth

Как удалить произвольный элемент из стека данных в языке Форт?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
N ROLL DROP
```

где `N` — номер элемента от вершины стека начиная с 0.

Например, фраза `4 3 2 1 0  3 ROLL DROP` оставит на стеке `4 2 1 0`.

Такой вариант [слова ROLL](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/ROLL) закреплен в спецификации начиная с [Forth-83](http://forth.sourceforge.net/standard/fst83/).

Comment: Спасибо Ruvim за публикацию моего вопроса и ответ на него :)
Исп. слова ROLL помогло неимоверно. Процитирую часть ответа из рассылки
***"Но, если это понадобилось, то скорей всего стек используется не по назначению."*** В самую точку, стек для подобных выкрутасов подходит мало. Лучше всего было б использовать список. Но его ещё надо реализовать и подключить :)

Comment: Реализовывать список имеет смысл или для обучения, или если [существующие](http://spf.sourceforge.net/docs/devel.ru.html#list) не подходят.